# How to create an <embed> svg button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I would like to create a custom checkbox in html that looks like this:

[image: Checkbox Image]

I generated an embed object containing and svg image and wrote a function that changes the color of the svg. My problem is that I can not add an onclick attribute to the embed object and therefore cannot call the function.

Note that the embed object is and has to be generated using JavaScript using the code below.

```
var new_checkbox = document.createElement('embed');
new_checkbox.setAttribute('class',"svg_check");
new_checkbox.setAttribute('onclick',"change_color("+C+","+i+")");
new_checkbox.setAttribute('src',"./images/check.svg");
new_checkbox.setAttribute('id',"svg_checkbox" + C + i);
new_skill.appendChild(new_checkbox);
```

I read that the onclick attribute should be added inside the svg. how do I achieve that in this case since I am not using inline svg.

Is there perhaps a simpler method to create an image button that changes color when clicked?

Comment: But you don't need `embed` to create custom checkboxes (and it's unsemantic). See [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-checkbox-radio/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use embed, or JavaScript / jQuery for this. You can make this using pure CSS:

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI';}
label input {display: none;}
label span {display: inline-block; width: 12px; height: 12px; background: #99f;}
label input:checked + span {background: #000;}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <span></span>
  Hello!
</label>
```

You can replace the `background` with using an image.